# Null Reference trying to save Item list

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a script for a class and I am running into a problem where I am getting the error

> "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object variable or With block variable not set.'

Here is the code that I am using to try and get it to write

```
Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem6.Click


    If SaveDialog.ShowDialog(txtScanNumber.Text) = DialogResult.OK Then

            Dim fileName As String = SaveDialog.FileName

            Dim sFile As New System.IO.FileStream(fileName,
            System.IO.FileMode.Create)

            Dim wFile As New System.IO.StreamWriter(sFile)

            wFile.Write(txtScanNumber.Text)

            wFile.Close()
           End If

    End Sub
```

I expect it to save to local drive and be able to recall it with a load function that I will add later.

Comment: The lines which wrap may be causing problems.  If I remember correctly you can't just arbitrarily wrap a line in VB like you can in more C-like languages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: ShowDialog() does not take a string argument.  Delete the argument or use `Me`.  Favor Option Strict On at the top of the source code file so the compiler can tell you that you are doing it wrong.